# django jquery admin problems

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin

I have added tinyMCE to my django admin which works fine but now I am getting errors showing up in firebug:

django is not defined
[Break on this error] })(django.jQuery);

This is my custom code:
[code]
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}

$(document).ready(function() {


 tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced"   //(n.b. no trailing comma, this will be critical as you experiment later)
 });

  });

{% endblock %}
[/code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery version included in Django's admin lives in a separate namespace.

So either replace each call of `$` in your script by `django.jQuery`, or make the `$` variable available in the scope by wrapping your code like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tinyMCE.init({mode: "textareas", theme: "advanced"});
    });
}(django.jQuery));
```